# encoding error when calling FileUtils.copy_entry in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, copy

I'm writing code for copy and paste recursively. 
But I got an encoding error when calling `FileUtils.copy_entry`

**Error Messages :**

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1535:in `join': incompatible character encodings: CP949 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1535:in `join'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1218:in `path'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:463:in `block in copy_entry'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1485:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1485:in `wrap_traverse'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1488:in `block in wrap_traverse'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `wrap_traverse'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1488:in `block in wrap_traverse'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `wrap_traverse'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:460:in `copy_entry'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:435:in `block in cp_r'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1558:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1574:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1556:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:434:in `cp_r'
    from copy_test.rb:11:in `copy_files'
    from copy_test.rb:81:in `block in <main>'
    from copy_test.rb:76:in `each'
    from copy_test.rb:76:in `<main>'
```

I'm calling `copy_entry` like this.

```
def copy_files(src, dst)  
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dst))
  FileUtils.copy_entry(src, dst)
end
```

There are some sub-folders and files named with my local language in `src`.
So I think `(Encoding::CompatibilityError)` occurs because of these sub-folders and files with local language (not English). 
When I tested with only Enlgish folders and files, It worked. 
But, I need non-English folders and files too.

How can I solve this problem?
Should I define a new method replacing `copy_entry`?

**My Codes ADDED:**

```rb
# -*- encoding: cp949 -*-
require 'fileutils'

LIST_FILE = "backup_target_list.txt"
DEST_FILE = "backup_dest.txt"

def copy_files(src, dst)  
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dst))
  FileUtils.copy_entry(src, dst)
end

def get_dst_base_name()
  cur_date = Time.now.to_s[0..9]
  return "backup_#{cur_date}"
end

def get_backup_list(list_file)
  if !File.exist?(list_file) then
    return nil
  end

  path_arr = []

  File.open(list_file, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line { |line|
      path_arr.push(make_path(line.gsub("\n", "")))
    }
  end

  return path_arr
end

def get_dest(dest_file)
  if !File.exist?(dest_file) then
    return nil
  end

  return File.open(dest_file, "r").readline
end

def make_path(*str)
  path_new = nil

  str.each do |item|    
    if item.class == Array then
      path_new = (path_new == nil ? File.join(item) : File.join(path_new, item)) 
    else 
      if item.include?(File::ALT_SEPARATOR) then
        path_new = (path_new == nil ? File.join(item.split(File::ALT_SEPARATOR)) : File.join(path_new, item.split(File::ALT_SEPARATOR)))
      else
        path_new = (path_new == nil ? File.join(item) : File.join(path_new, item))
      end        
    end
  end

  return path_new
end

get_backup_list(LIST_FILE).each do |path|
  src = path
  tmp = src.split(File::SEPARATOR)
  dst = make_path(get_dest(DEST_FILE), get_dst_base_name, tmp[1..tmp.length])
  print "src: #{src}\n=> dst: #{dst}\n"
  copy_files(src, dst)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you are using cp949 encoding, and the raised error tells CP949 and UTF-8 are incompatible, so why you just using UTF-8 encoding? So replace the shebang with

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

And to ensure all the characters read from LIST_FILE are utf-8 encoded, add the following:

```
line.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Yes. It is like `1월1일.csv`, `3월3일오후.csv`

Comment: It should be ok with the characters since they can be utf-8 encoded. Can you please paste how you call the copy_files function? The error raises in `join`, which used to mix dir and basename together.

Comment: OK. I just added my codes at the bottom of my question.